# How can I display the "Add to wish list" button on products' slider?

Tags: magento2

I have this phtml file with the following code :

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile
$randomSlideId = rand(1000, 10000);
?>
<script>
    require([
        'jquery',
        'Eadesigndev_Slider/js/owlcarousel',
        'domReady!'
    ], function ($) {
        $("#ctslider_products_list_<?php echo $randomSlideId?>").owlCarousel({
            nav: true,
            dots: false,
            loop: true,
            items: 3,
            autoplay: false,
            autoplayHoverPause: true,
            responsive: {
                0: {
                    items: 1,
                    center: true
                },

                480: {
                    items: 1
                },

                640: {
                    items: 2
                },

                768: {
                    items: 3
                },

                1024: {
                    items: <?php echo $block->getData('product_slide_count');?>
                }
            }
        });
    })
</script>
<?php
/**
 * Template for displaying products list widget
 *
 * @var $block \Magento\CatalogWidget\Block\Product\ProductsList
 */
?>
<?php if ($exist = ($block->getProductCollection() && $block->getProductCollection()->getSize())): ?>
    <?php
    $type = 'widget-product-grid';

    $mode = 'grid';

    $image = 'new_products_content_widget_grid';
    $title = $block->getTitle() ? __($block->getTitle()) : '';
    $items = $block->getProductCollection()->getItems();
    $showWishlist = true;
    $showCompare = true;
    $showCart = true;
    $templateType = \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ReviewRendererInterface::DEFAULT_VIEW;
    $description = false;
    ?>
    <div class="block widget block-products-list <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */
    echo $mode; ?>">
        <?php if ($title): ?>
            <div class="block-title">
                <strong><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */
                    echo $title; ?></strong>
            </div>
        <?php endif ?>

        <div class="block-content">
            <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */
            echo '<!--' . $image . '-->' ?>
            <div class="products-<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */
            echo $mode; ?>
            <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */
            echo $mode; ?>">
                <ol id="ctslider_products_list_<?php echo $randomSlideId ?>"
                    class="product-items <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */
                    echo $type; ?>">
                    <?php $iterator = 1; ?>
                    <?php foreach ($items as $_item): ?>
                        <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */
                        echo ($iterator++ == 1) ? '<li class="product-item">' : '</li><li class="product-item">' ?>
                        <div class="product-item-info">
                            <?php
                            $finalPrice = $_item->getPriceInfo()->getPrice('final_price')->getAmount()->getValue();
                            $regularPrice = $_item->getPriceInfo()->getPrice('regular_price')->getAmount()->getValue();
                            if (($_item->getAttributeText('info_disp') != 'Nu') && ($regularPrice > 0) && ($finalPrice > 0)) {
                                if ($_item->isAvailable()) {
                                    //Cu stoc
                                    if ($_item->getAttributeText('farapret') != 'fara_cos_pret') {
                                        $discount = ($regularPrice - $finalPrice);
                                        $percent = ($discount / $regularPrice) * 100;
                                        ?>
                                        <div class="product-percent">
                                            <?php
                                            if (!$percent == 0) {
                                                ?>
                                                <div class="content-percent">
                                                    <p class="percent">
                                                        <?php echo '-' . round($percent); ?>%
                                                    </p>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="promo-text">
                                                    <p>PROMO</p>
                                                </div>
                                                <?php
                                            } ?>

                                        </div>
                                        <?php
                                    } else {
                                        ?>
                                        <div class="product-percent">
                                            <div class="promo-text">
                                                <p>PROMO</p>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <?php
                                    }
                                } else {
                                    //Fara stoc
                                    ?>
                                    <div class="product-percent">
                                        <div class="content-percent">
                                            <p class="unavailable">STOC</p>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="promo-text">
                                            <p class="unavailable">EPUIZAT</p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <?php
                                }
                            }

                            ?>



                            <a href="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */
                            echo $block->getProductUrl($_item) ?>"
                               class="product-item-photo"><?php echo $block->getImage($_item, $image)->toHtml(); ?>
                            </a>
                            <div class="product-item-details">
                                <strong class="product-item-name">
                                    <a title="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml($_item->getName()) ?>"
                                       href="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */
                                       echo $block->getProductUrl($_item) ?>"
                                       class="product-item-link">
                                        <?php
                                        $productName = $block->escapeHtml($_item->getName());
                                        if (strlen($productName) > 90) {
                                            echo substr($productName, 0, 90) . '...';
                                        } else {
                                            echo $productName;
                                        }
                                        ?></a>
                                </strong>
                                <?php
                                if ($_item->getAttributeText('info_disp') != 'Nu') {
                                    if ($_item->getAttributeText('farapret') != 'fara_cos_pret') {
                                        if ( $_item->getFinalPrice()>0){
                                            echo $block->getProductPriceHtml($_item, $type);
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                                ?>
                                <?php if ($templateType): ?>
                                    <?php echo $block->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_item, $templateType) ?>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                            </div>
                            <a href="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */
                            echo $block->getProductUrl($_item) ?>"
                               class="product-item-photo">
                                <div class="details">
                                    <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Vezi detalii'))?></span>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <?php echo ($iterator == count($items) + 1) ? '</li>' : '' ?>
                    <?php endforeach ?>
                </ol>
            </div>
            <?php echo $block->getPagerHtml() ?>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

This code displays a slider with products . How can I add to each product the Add to wish list button ?
[image]

I have added wishlist.phtml, but still it doesn't work
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add wishlist by using below code:

```
echo $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Wishlist\Block\Catalog\Product\ProductList\Item\AddTo\Wishlist')->setProduct($_product)->setTemplate("Magento_Wishlist::catalog/product/list/addto/wishlist.phtml")->toHtml();
```

Where $_product is product object and it is your code $_item.

Comment: ->setProduct($_product) Here $_product is product object so first confirm that $_item is product object then it will work. If still not work then load product and check.

Comment: echo $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Wishlist\Block\Catalog\Product\ProductList\Item\AddTo\Wishlist')->setProduct($_item)->setTemplate("Magento_Wishlist::catalog/product/list/addto/wishlist.phtml")->toHtml();
    I have used your code , but it doesn't work for me , it may be because I don't have a  Magento_Wishlist folder in my theme ? Where can I get it from ?

Comment: It may happened due to theme. you can copy wishlist.phtml from vendor and put to your theme. 
Vendor path : vendor/magento/module-wishlist/view/frontend/templates/catalog/product/list/addto/wishlist.phtml

Comment: I have added the file, but still it doesn't work, I have added two images in my issue above

Comment: Have you enabled wishlist from admin? Configure the Wish List. On the Admin sidebar, go to Stores > Settings > Configuration. In the left panel, expand Customers and choose Wish List. the General Options section and verify that Enabled is set to Yes .

If you enabled then add any comment in wishlist.phtml file and check that comment in showing in front side or not?

Comment: is it works? Clear cache if needed.

Comment: Yes, it worked !! thank you so much